# Library/linker problems mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have been writing some C and C++ infrastructure for general-purpose applications. At the moment it's a work-in-progress and consists of config parsing with Lua, logging functionality and a client/server API that uses my own network protocol/messaging API.

I have organised the code into two libraries: one for the C code (libmarlin.so) and one for the C++ code (libmarlin++.so). My reason for having two instead of one is incidentally the original issue I'm still having with the C++ library only: linking an application to it will cause "undefined reference" errors to either the Lua code or the code in my C library plus some other random C++ "operator new" references, depending on the ordering of the `-l` switches in the Makefile. I can't find a combination that satisfies the dependencies. I already understand the importance of the ordering on these switches and have tried suggestions as per questions on this site; all to no avail.

I will paste what I think is relevant here to save copying copious amounts of code. If you need anything else either ask or you can clone my GitHub repository: https://github.com/adamd1008/marlin. You'll need the Lua code in a folder outside the repo called `lua-5.3.2` or change the Makefiles as appropriate. Also note that I modified the Lua makefile to build a dynamic library instead of the default static lib, hence my use of `-llua` when building. (That was really just to try and fix the underlying issue.)

Compilation:

```
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/adam/marlin/src'
** Compiling file 'log.c'
gcc -std=c99 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 -DLOG_UUID=\"27dc17c4-bd53-11e5-bb37-a02bb831a7e4\" log.c -o log.o
** Compiling file 'msg.c'
gcc -std=c99 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 -DLOG_UUID=\"27dc17c4-bd53-11e5-bb37-a02bb831a7e4\" msg.c -o msg.o
** Linking file 'libmarlin.so.1.0.0'
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmarlin.so.1.0.0 -o ../lib/libmarlin.so.1.0.0 log.o msg.o
ln -sf libmarlin.so.1.0.0 ../lib/libmarlin.so
** Compiling file 'M_App.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -pedantic -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 M_App.cpp -o M_App.o
** Compiling file 'M_Field.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -pedantic -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 M_Field.cpp -o M_Field.o
** Compiling file 'M_FieldMap.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -pedantic -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 M_FieldMap.cpp -o M_FieldMap.o
** Compiling file 'M_Msg.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -pedantic -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 M_Msg.cpp -o M_Msg.o
** Compiling file 'M_MsgApp.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -fPIC -pedantic -I../../lua-5.3.2/src -DMAJOR_VER=1 -DMINOR_VER=0 -DBUILD_VER=0 M_MsgApp.cpp -o M_MsgApp.o
** Linking file 'libmarlin++.so.1.0.0'
gcc -shared -L../../lua-5.3.2/src -llua -Wl,-soname,libmarlin++.so.1.0.0 -o ../lib/libmarlin++.so.1.0.0 M_App.o M_Field.o M_FieldMap.o M_Msg.o M_MsgApp.o
ln -sf libmarlin++.so.1.0.0 ../lib/libmarlin++.so
make -C test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/marlin/src/test'
** Compiling file 'msg_test.c'
gcc -std=c99 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -I../../../lua-5.3.2/src msg_test.c -o msg_test.o
** Linking file 'msg_test.o'
gcc -L../../lib -L../../../lua-5.3.2/src -lm -ldl -llua -lmarlin -o msg_test msg_test.o
** Compiling file 'app_test.cpp'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -rdynamic -pedantic -I../../../lua-5.3.2/src app_test.cpp -o app_test.o
** Linking file 'app_test.o'
g++ -L../../lib -L../../../lua-5.3.2/src -lm -ldl -llua -lmarlin -lmarlin++ -o app_test app_test.o
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_tolstring(lua_State*, int, unsigned long*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_type(lua_State*, int)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `luaL_loadfilex(lua_State*, char const*, char const*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_getglobal(lua_State*, char const*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_geti(lua_State*, int, long long)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs(lua_State*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_typename(lua_State*, int)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_settop(lua_State*, int)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_close(lua_State*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_pushstring(lua_State*, char const*)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `lua_gettable(lua_State*, int)'
../../lib/libmarlin++.so: undefined reference to `luaL_newstate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [app_test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/marlin/src/test'
make[1]: *** [test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/marlin/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I suspect there's a simple explanation but I can't work it out. As per the last compilation step, `-llua` is specified before either of my libraries, but libmarlin++.so still has issues even though it itself is also linked to the Lua library (though I'm not sure it has any effect when building a dynamic library?).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of code in your Github repository, so a thorough analysis would take time, but, at first look, this seems to be "The Case of the Missing `extern "C"`" (pun intended).

From C++ code, when including C headers, you need `extern "C"`. There are several ways to do it. First, when including, like:

```
extern "C" {
#include "the_c_header.h"
}
```

Second, in the header itself:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

.... contents of the C header...

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Third is time consuming to illustrate, basically, add `extern "C"` to any declaration in the C header.

There may be other issues, but, I'd first try this.

Comment: Oh god, yeah I missed one :( Normally I don't miss any headers for that, thanks.

Comment: @Doddy glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use C code inside your C++ program you should declare all C prototypes as `extern "C"`. So try wrapping all Lua includes in your program like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}
```

Comment: The same should be accomplished by `#include <lua.hpp>` (at least lua 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3)